# Entry saved to two tables has one to many relationship in mvc 4 code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I simplified my problem as i could ,I have two classes `Employee` ,`Departments`
I supposed to make a one to many relationship between them

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string salary { get; set; }
        public virtual Department depatments { get; set; }
    }
```

//////////////////////

```
    public class Department
    {
        public Department()
        {
            this.employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> employees { get; set; }
    }
```

and that is my context class

```
public class myEntity :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> employees {get;set;}
        public DbSet<Department> Departments {get;set;}
    }
```

well, I have created a `Create` ActionResult in order to be able to add new record to `Employee` and filled a `selectlist` with `Department` table/Class
And sent it to view by `viewbag`

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.xx = new SelectList(mycontext.Departments, "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee emp)
        {

            mycontext.employees.Add(emp);
            mycontext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
        }
```

And there is the `view`

```
**@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
      <fieldset>
            <legend>Employee</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.salary)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.salary)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.salary)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depatments)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.depatments.Id,@ViewBag.xx as SelectList)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.salary)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
```

I ran it, every thing is ok and database created.
the view dropdownlist render  `ID`  And `Name` as it should.

Normally ,Every Employee record should have `Department ID` as a Foreign Key.
The problem is When i add new record to `Employee` it add a new record in `Department` where it should pick just `ID` and add it to `Employee`

Note: I filled the `Department` first With no problem

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different context to save then it should work without this issue. Your Departments entity is still being tracked in the first context and this is the reason for the issue.